# Serving multiple Rails apps from a single IP: static assets not found (nginx + Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, asset-pipeline, passenger

I've got nginx and Passenger set up on a VPS to serve two Rails apps from two separate paths. Here's my goal -- to serve each of the Rails apps from separate sub-URIs.

```
123.123.123.123/app1
123.123.123.123/app2
```

Following the Passenger + nginx documentation, I have set up the following `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 123.123.123.123;

        location /app1 {
            alias /u/apps/app1_project_name;
            passenger_enabled on;
            passenger_base_uri /app1;
        }

        location /app2 {
            alias /u/apps/app2_project_name;
            passenger_enabled on;
            passenger_base_uri /app2;
        }
    }
```

I have created a symbolic link in the `/u/apps/app1_project_name` and `/u/apps/app2_project_name` directories called `app1` and `app2` respectively linking to `./current/public` in both cases.

When I access the site, all of the *pages* appear correctly, but none of the static assets appear to work! If I view the page source, I see links to pages like this: `/app1/home/index`. That link works if I click it.

However, there are also links like this: `/app1/assets/application-1b13569e9620782f423d4cd3ce931750.css` for the .css and .js assets. **But they're not found when I click the links!**

Is something wrong with my nginx + Passenger config that it's not routing these properly? Examining the `public/assets` folder shows that the files are in fact being precompiled correctly and do appear there.

Comment: I think my answer is totally unrelated to the new content of your question :)

Comment: @QumaraSixOneTour Yeah, sorry about that. I think I've found something that fixes the issue. You can add it on to your answer and I'll mark your answer as correct. I think it has something to do with nginx not being able to serve the static assets correctly if you have a sub-URI set up? So I went into production.rb and set `config.serve_static_assets = true`, and now it works! Just toss that info in at the end of your answer and I'll give it to ya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the assets , that are causing error, should be included in your `application.js` manifest file like this :

```
//= require hsv_to_rgb
//= require overlays
//= require initialize
```

and remove this from your production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( hsv_to_rgb.js initialize.js overlays.js )
```

Normally after deploy , in your `public/assets` on your server (in production env) you should see only different versions of `application.js` and `application.css`.

Consider to place your call to the external javascript (best explained [here](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-javascript-include-external.html)) right before your `application.js` in your view template , something like this :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

EDIT: The actual problem has been solved by @aardvarkk , simply changing the setting in `production.rb` like this :

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

The configuration of `nginx` includes  a sub-URI set up.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. As far as I understand, this is just putting all of the .js files into the single application.js, but my problem appears to be that it can't find the assets at all.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite my question as I've gained some new insights into what's going on. Thanks for your answer.